# Nginx hiphop php - Assign Server variables dynamic how to?

Tags: php, hiphop

We are trying to make use of hiphop php for our domain. We are using nginx running in port 80, and hiphop in port 4247, in our PHP code we have used few server variables like DOCUMENT_ROOT, HTTP_TRUE_CLIENT_IP etc., the problem here is, the server variables are not taking the appropriate value. In few google search i came to know that we can specify server variables (under ServerVariables) while starting the hiphop compiled source as server, but i want to know is there any other way we can make it dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

If you need dynamic variables, why do they have to be in $_SERVER? Shouldn't you just make a function to figure them out?